# Cannot find Mac app in applications folder

Tags: cocoa, macos, terminal, installation

I installed an app I wrote using the terminal with the command.

```
sudo installer -store -pkg "/Users/MyName/Desktop/HelloWorld.pkg" -target /
```

It appears to have worked but I cannot find the app anywhere in the Applications folder. The terminal spits out this

```
installer: Installation Check: Passed
installer: Volume Check: Passed
installer: Starting install
installer: Install 0.0% complete
2010-12-08 00:45:26.272 installer[18658:2303] PackageKit: *** Missing bundle identifier: /Library/Receipts/Flip4Mac QuickTime Components.pkg
2010-12-08 00:45:26.275 installer[18658:2303] PackageKit: *** Missing bundle identifier: /Library/Receipts/Flip4Mac Web Plugins.pkg
installer: Install 9.1% complete
installer: Install 16.7% complete
installer: Install 23.1% complete
installer: Install 28.6% complete
installer: Install 33.3% complete
installer: Install 37.5% complete
installer: Install 41.2% complete
installer: Install 100.0% complete
installer: Finished install
```

Also why is the terminal telling me about an application that is unrelated to the application that I am installing?

Any suggestions? Thanks.

**EDIT**
I fixed the problem by clicking on the installer package. I then opened the log and viewed all messages. I then look for the install path and proceeded to the directory pointed by the path. I deleted everything in the directory. I ran the installer again and the application is installed in the applications folder.

**EDIT2**
I found this command useful. It basically tells you where the app is being installed on your machine.

```
sudo installer -verbose -dumplog -store -pkg "HelloWorld.pkg" -target /
```

Comment: Try running with `-verboseR` and editing your question to include that output. Alternatively, try installing with the Installer application (the GUI one), opening up its log, setting the detail to full, and editing your question to include that output.

Comment: I looked at the log and said the application was moved from the Applications folder to the project build folder. How do I prevent it from doing that? Thanks

Comment: The two warnings in your log can be safely ignored. The installer will warn about missing bundle identifiers in receipts any time it opens up the receipts list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I looked at the log and said the application was moved from the Applications folder to the project build folder. How do I prevent it from doing that?

Gaze up at the sky, shake your fist, and yell “DAMN YOU RELOCAAATIOONN!”

Then turn that off in PackageMaker.